# How to get unique records of specific columns of data table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable imported from Excel file.
Data i need is only unique from specific columns of the DataTable.
The unique data i meant is like when a command DISTINCT is used in SQL Select Query.
I want to get the list of the unique data from the DataTable Column and put them into List
I think LinQ can be used for this matter but i'm not so familiar with it.
I was thinking of code like this below

```
var data is from MyDataTable
  where MyDataTable.ColumnName = "SpecificColumn"
  select MyDataTable["SpecificColumn"]).UniqueData;

List<string> MyUniqueData = new List<string>();

foreach(object obj in data)
{
  if(MyUniqueData.NotContain(obj))
    MyUniqueData.add(obj);
}
```

I hope someone can drop off some knowledge to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
var unique = data.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `.Distinct()`. [See MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx). You can specify your own comparer if you need something specific and it will return only unique records.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Datatable or DataView, inorder to get unique records from a column, you have to write this.
this would be simple.

```
DataTable dtNew = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ColName"); // for Datatable

DataTable dtnew= dv.ToTable(true, "ColName"); // for DataView
```